# How does electronic view finder preview shutter speed?

Tags: evf

Like title mentioned, how does mirrorless or dslr's live viewfinder previews the different shutter speed? In actuality, when the picture is taken, the shutter actually has to close for that amount of time right? So how does the preview work?

Comment: "the shutter actually has to close for that amount of time right?" – **No.** The shutter has to *open* to allow light through.

Comment: @xiota To be fair, in live view or a mirrorless camera, the shutter does need to close in order to then open.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't preview the shutter speed, but emulates the total amount of light received for the given aperture, speed and ISO. Shoot anything that moves (a fan for instance) and you'll see that it is not frozen in the preview as it should be if the display were also emulating the actual shutter speed.

Comment: But, but, but... I thought with EVFs WYSIWYG?

Comment: @MichaelC yes, with suitable definitions of "see" and "get".

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. How accurate is the emulation? How does it work so well?